# Can't Make pdf of Math Help Document in Lyx 2.14

Tags: lyx

Using Lyx 2.14 on Windows 7. When I try to create a pdf of the built-in Math help document I get the following error:

LaTex Error: Command \@textsubscript already defined.

I have had no problems creating pdfs from my own documents.

Comment: Perhaps this is linked to the fact since version 2015, `\textsubscript` is in the kernel of LaTeX, and doesn't require anymore the `fixltx2e` package. In other words, the source-code should be updated.

Comment: Could be as @Bernard said, but (1) I don't see this error on Ubuntu with TeX Live 2015, and even if it is the case, we still need to provide compatibility for TeX Live 2014, so I suppose that we should do something like "if defined".